# Operator norm composition operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, dynamical-systems, koopman-operator

Let $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R},[0,1])$ and consider the associated composition/Koopman operator on $L^2([0,1])$ defined for any $f\in L^2([0,1])$ by
$$
C_g(f)(x) :=f\circ g(x).
$$
Are there known bounds for the operator norm of $C_g$?

Comment: Also context is missing: where does the question come from, what are your thoughts. etc.

Comment: some assumption seems to be missing: if $g(x)=1$ for all $x$, then $f\circ g(x) = f(1)$ is not a well-defined map on $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: @daw Right, this article: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0093791.pdf (page 17) characterizes $g$ for which $C_g$ is a bounded linear operator by $g$ is bijective and $\partial g^{-1}$ is well-defined and essentially bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $C_g$ may be unbounded.
Let $g(x)=x^2.$
Then the function $f(x)=x^{-1/4}$ is belongs to  $L^2(0,1),$ while
$f\circ g(x)=x^{-1/2}$ doesn't.

As was observed by @daw the operator $C_g$ is well defined if the level sets $\{x\in [0,1]\,:\, g(x)=a\}$ have Lebesgue measure equal $0.$

Comment: and daw I believe I have worked out the problem (with correct sufficient conditions on $g$) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479616/operator-norm-of-composition-koopman-operator
If you want to take a look.