# Operator Norm of Composition/Koopman Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, dynamical-systems, koopman-operator

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous bijective map and suppose that $g^{-1}$ is well-defined, of class $C^1$, and satisfies
$$
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\, |\operatorname{det}J_{g^{-1}}(x)|=:M<\infty.
$$

Fix a positive integer $n$.
A perturbation of the argument of [this article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0093793.pdf) shows that the associated composition operator
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_g: L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n) & \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\\
f &\mapsto f\circ g
\end{aligned}
$$
is a well-defined bounded-linear operator.  Actually this follows from the change-of-variable formulate from multivariate calculus since we have assumed that $g^{-1}$ is of class $C^1$.

If I am not mistaken then the operator norm of $C_g$ can be estimated as follows.  Suppose that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the $\|f\|_{L^2}=1$.  Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
   C_g(f) 
:= &
   \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\, 
      \|f\circ g(x)\|^2
   dx
\\ = &
   \int_{u \in g^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\, 
      |\det J_g^{-1}(u)| \|f\circ g\circ g^{-1}(u)\|^2
   du
\\ = &
   \int_{u \in g^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\, 
      |\det J_g^{-1}(u)| \|f(u)\|^2
   du
\\ \leq &
   \sup_{v\in \mathbb{R}^n}\, |\det (J_g^{-1}(v))|
   \,
    \int_{u \in g^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\, 
      \|f(u)\|^2
   du
\\
\leq & M \|f\|_{L^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Whence we conclude that
$$
  \|C_g\|_{op}
:= 
  \sup_{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n);\, \|f\|_{L^2}=1}\,
  \|C_g(f)\|_{L^2}
\leq 
  M \|f\|
=
  M
.
$$

Is this proof correct?

If so does anyone know of sharper estimates?

---

Interesting related note: I have found several results on the operator norm of composition operators when the involved spaces are not $L^2$ but rather the complex Hardy space (e.g. [this 2016 paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X15008112) or [this old Annals of Math paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971314))

Another cute reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00325.pdf